# On a shared computer, how to hide sensitve information from super users?

Tags: ubuntu, shared-folders

So I'm on a shared machine. And would like to know if there is any software or protocol that tries to keep things tidy for you. Any encryption I can use on my home or anything similar to keep my privacy from other root users.

Comment: Did Google turn up anything useful for you? If yes, why didn't it work?

Comment: Basically no. There are ways to encrypt your files so that they are protected when you are not using the computer, but a superuser has access to your memory (and to what you type when you enter some password), so basically there is no privacy on a computer you don't manage yourseff alone.